# Default initialization confusion

Tags: c++

In my C++ Primer, 5th Edition, they say on page 43 about default initialization (emphasis mine):

> The value of an object of built-in type that is not explicitly initialized depends on where it is defined. **Variables defined outside any function body are initialized to zero.**

Later, on page 73, they define a new class like this:

```
struct Sales_data {
  std::string bookNo;
  unsigned units_sold = 0;
  double revenue = 0.0;
};
```

This is supposed to provide an example of the new standard's in-class initializers. In this case, `units_sold` and `revenue` will be initialized to zero. If they are not, they say, the variables will be default-initialized.

But this is my question: What is the point of this in-class initialization? What's wrong with letting them just default-initialize? The reason I ask is that they already mentioned that **variables defined outside any function body are initialized to zero**, and in this case, these variables are not inside any function - they are in a class definition. So the default-initialization should initialize these variables to zero, shouldn't it?

Comment: The data members would **not** be initialized to `0`, so either the quote is wrong, or there is some missing context.

Answer (score 2):

The quote seems to be in wrong context. A variable can have at least 3 states:

1. **Default initialized**: Variable is initialized inside the constructor
   based on argument or no argument. *Value initialized* is a special case of this type
2. **In-class initialized**: The C++11 feature which you have presented in
   your code
3. **Uninitialized**: Variable's initialization is not addressed anywhere
   and it can contain any garbage value. Some compilers may automatically make it `0` or give a warning

Answer (score 1):

The first statement about "Variables defined outside any function body" refers to objects with static linkage, i.e., variables declared in namespaces: These are zero initialized. The members in the `struct` get initialized wherever this `struct` lives. If it lives on the stack or is allocated on the heap, the built-in variable won't get initialized without the assignments, e.g., when used like this:

```
void f() {
    Sales_data data;
}
```

Even without the initialization in the declaration, they would get zero-initialized if the `struct` is used like this, though:

```
Sales_data global; // <--- the "outside any function body" case
void f() {
    Sales_data data0 = {};
    Sales_data data1 = Sales_data();
    Sales_data data2{};
}
```

However, these all require cooperation by the user of the `struct` and initializing them explicitly makes sure the values are set.